# Which form should be used: ろくしゅうかん or ろくしゅう?

Tags: suffixes, time

The full sentence, which I had to learn was:

> わたしは　ろくしゅうかんまえに　にほんに　きました

But I don't understand the meaning of the "-kan" that follows ろくしゅう
Can anyone please enlighten me when and why I have to use that suffix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The かん here is 間 in kanji, and this is used as a suffix to refer to a span of time.  ろくしゅう in your sentence is spelled 六週 in kanji and means "six weeks", but in a way that is more ambiguous than the English.  Various suffixes can be added on the end to make things more specific, like 目{め} to mean "the sixth week", or 分{ぶん} to indicate six weeks' worth of something, or 間{かん} for a span of time.  Have a look partway down [the Weblio entry for 間](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E9%96%93), for sense 1 under the かん reading for some examples of how this かん is used.

Comment: @ChristofWalker:  While `ろく` is written as `六` in kanji, you will only occasionally see it written this way.  More likely you will just see it as `6週間`.