# When should I use 週 versus 週間 for "week"?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I just decided I needed to know the word for week and found both 週 and 週間 mean "week".

Can I get by as a beginner with only 週間? Or when should each one be used?

Comment: Apparent duplicate of [Which form should be used: ろくしゅうかん or ろくしゅう?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18057/which-form-should-be-used-ろくしゅうかん-or-ろくしゅう)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know both, and their differences.

Measures of time are often suffixed with -間, and in the case of a measure of time with weeks as the unit, -週間 is the preferred way to say "week" as in "an interval of X weeks".

For example:

> 一週間 = one week's time (or more colloquially, one week)
>
> 卒業式まであと(残り)わずか一週間です。(or 卒業式まであと一週間しかありません。)
>   There's only one week left until the graduation ceremony.

When speaking of a point in time that is a relative point in time, you would use just -週 as the word for "week".

For example:

> 来週 = next week
>
> 来週の月曜日は僕の誕生日なんです。
>   Next week Monday is my birthday.

So, 週 is "week" in a relative sense, while 週間 is "week" in a quantifiable sense. Neither of these words would completely serve on their own, as they usually form a part of another word that provides clearer context, but knowing what context they provide to a word helps with determining how you'll use them.

Answer (score 3):

For beginners, I recommend the following:

- Use `週` when you specify a week. e.g. `第5週` = the fifth week
- Use `週間` when you refer to a time span. e.g. `5週間` = five weeks.

This is preferable while you may `週` instead of `週間`.